# Echo Dot - Can you ask Alexa to remind you of your favorite TV shows?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I’m able to find TV skills for Alexa, but none of them (that I can see) will check the schedule and remind you of your favorite TV shows.  I know I can set a reminder for them, but if the show time changes or the season ends, I don’t want to have to edit every reminder.  Is there a skill that does this?  Or maybe is it possible to create one?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any already existing skills, but building one should be possible with the latest API which supports alarms/alerts https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/alerts.html

The harder problem will most likely be getting hold of the TV listing data in a usable format.

If you are lucky enough to be in a region that uses DVB-T then it might be possible to extract the 7 day listing that are broadcast over the air, otherwise look at the MythTv project as that had listings collectors for many different regions

Comment: https://www.pogdesign.co.uk/cat/ can generate calendar files with TV airing data.